# how to check fckeditor is loaded completely or not

Tags: fckeditor

Once loaded, the editor registers a global object called FCKeditorAPI. This object offers the entry point to interact with any editor instance placed in a page and i am receiving an error stating  FCKeditorAPI is not defined so is there any method in javascript to check whether fckeditor is loaded or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if( typeof( FCKeditorAPI ) !== "undefined" )
{
     /* any logic you want */
}
```

Comment: although you cannot run this code immediately after creating Fck instance because code will not run, but if you want to trap it like an event you need to run it via setInterval() function.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3 (ckeditor) there is instanceReady

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
  doWhateverWith(ev);
});
```

Which version are you using?

Comment: i am using 2.6.4 is there any thing for this version